# Catching WM_POWERBROADCAST in a TWinControl child control

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a `TWinControl` that needs to catch `WM_POWERBROADCAST` messages, but they never seem to reach it despite adding the message handler to the control's `VCL_MESSAGE_MAP`. I've also tried a custom `WndProc()` and that also never receives these messages. Other messages are working fine.

I can catch the message successfully in the main form, but it's never passed to my controls.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_PAINT, TMessage, WMPaint); // Works
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_ERASEBKGND, TMessage, WMEraseBackground); // Works
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_POWERBROADCAST, TMessage, WMPower); // Doesn't work!
END_MESSAGE_MAP(inherited);
```

Comment: Best guess: That message isn't sent to your control, but likely to either the form on which it is, or to the application. Try catching it there (just to verify or not).

Comment: Yes, the Message gets to the form: Can the control notify the form that it wants the message? (The form *could* explicitly forward the message the the control, but that rather turns the architecture upside-down..

Comment: @Roddy There is no mechanism in place to handle that automatically. You will have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_POWERBROADCAST` is sent only to top-level windows, never to child windows.  So, you have a few choices:

- have your WinControl intercept the message that is sent to the hidden `TApplication` window by using the `TApplication.HookMainWindow()` method. Be sure to remove the hook when your WinControl is destroyed.

```cpp
__fastcall TMyControl::TMyControl(TComponent *Owner)
    : TWinControl(Owner)
{
    Application->HookMainWindow(&AppHook);
}

__fastcall TMyControl::~TMyControl()
{
    Application->UnhookMainWindow(&AppHook);
}

bool __fastcall TMyControl::AppHook(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
    {
        // ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

- intercept the message that is sent to the `TForm` window, either by applying a `MESSAGE_MAP` to the Form class, or by overriding the Form's virtual `WndProc()` method, and then have the From forward the message to your WinControl.

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
  ...
  VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_POWERBROADCAST, TMessage, WMPowerBroadcast);
END_MESSAGE_MAP(inherited); 

...

void __fastcall TForm1::WMPowerBroadcast(TMessage &Message)
{
    inherited::Dispatch(&Message);
    MyControl->Perform(Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
}
```

Or:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    inherited::WndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
        MyControl->Perform(Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
}
```

- have your WinControl create its own hidden top-level window by using the RTL's `AllocateHWnd()` function.

```cpp
private:
    HWND FPowerWnd;
    void __fastcall PowerWndProc(TMessage &Message);

...

__fastcall TMyControl::TMyControl(TComponent *Owner)
    : TWinControl(Owner)
{
    FPowerWnd = AllocateHWnd(&PowerWndProc);
}

__fastcall TMyControl::~TMyControl()
{
    DeallocateHWnd(FPowerWnd);
}

void __fastcall TMyControl::PowerWndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        Message.Result = ::DefWindowProc(FPowerWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, #1 will work fine for me.